# Change font size of likert plot legend and value label arrangement

Tags: font-size, legend

The default font size of the likert plot of the HH package is small and I want to increase its size for reading. I also want to control the order of the labeling value of the legend.

To get my value labels to be ordered correctly I have had to recode my data as "1 Not Valuable", "2 Neutral", and "3 Valuable". I do not want to have the "1", "2", and "3" listed, and simply want it listed as "Not Valuable", "Neutral", and "Valuable", however, when I try and list the values as categorical variables, the value defaults to alphabetical order (e.g., "Neutral", "Not Valuable", "Valuable").  I want the values to be in the order "Not Valuable", "Neutral", "Valuable".

Here is my current code and data (a)

```
          Value
Age        1 Not Valuable 2 Neutral 3 Valuable
  18-25                 8         4          8
  25.01-35             17        12         22
  35.01-45             10        19         18
  45.01-55             11        15         22
  55.01-65             27        25         34
  65.01-93             37        40         30

age=likert(a, ylab='Age Category', main='AGE DISTRIBUTION', 
    as.percent=TRUE,  col=c('gray70', 'gray48', 'black'))
```

I have also tried using the "theme" function to control text size with the code:

```
+theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12))
```

However, I get the R error that states

> could not find function theme

I have not found any information on controlling the order of value scale in the legend.

Comment: `theme` is a `ggplot2` function and will probably not work with plots generated by the `HH` package. In order to use the `theme` function, you have to load the `ggplot2` library. This can be done by typing `require(ggplot2)` in the console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue and had to use a command from the lattice package. Add this to your code:

```
auto.key.in = list(cex = 1.2)
```

adjusting the number to the font size you desire.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the font size. However, I am still having the problems with ordering the categorical variables in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

check ?likert.plot :

you can then use

```
plot (age, legend.position="right", group.order = a$Age)
```